# not sloved (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.' )

Tags: c#

this is my code and giv me error wen im tap save data butom
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'
**cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

hi
this is my code and giv me error wen im tap save data butom
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'
**cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevComponents.DotNetBar;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace itfamco
{
    public partial class frminfo : OfficeForm
    {
        public frminfo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (connectionString: @"Data Source=ABDOLI;Initial Catalog=FORM;User ID=sa;Password=Pass1921");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        private void frminfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (ID.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("لطفا کد را واردکنید");
                return;
            }
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into TIT(ID,NAME,INNUM,TNUM,PHONENUM,IP,MAC,BOS,MONITOR,MK,PHONE,PRINTER,TPHONE,JOB,OTHER,GOZAR)values(@NAME,@INNUM,@TNUM,@PHONENUM,@IP,@MAC,@BOS,@MONITOR,@MK,@PHONE,@PRINTER,@TPHONE,@JOB,@OTHER,,@GOZAR,,@ID)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",int.Parse(ID.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", NAME.Text?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INNUM", INNUM.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TNUM", TNUM.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHONENUM", PHONENUM.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IP", IP2.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAC", MAC.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONITOR", MONITOR.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MK", MK.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PHONE", PHONE.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRINTER", PRINTER.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TPHONE", TPHONE.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JOB", JOB.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OTHER", OTHER.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GOZAR", GOZAR.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BOS", BOS.Text ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
            con.Open();
            
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("ثبت انجام شد");

        }

        private void groupPanel3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PHONENUM_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

how fix that

Comment: Your line at `cmd.CommandText` has a few duplicate `,,` inside of it. I think these needs to be removed or filled, at least with empty values.

Comment: `,@OTHER,,@GOZAR,,@ID)` <== um, don't have `,,` ? also, should `@ID` be moved to the first position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, keep your code *formatted* and the problem will be *evident*; your query should be

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
insert into TIT(
  ID, NAME, INNUM, TNUM, PHONENUM, IP, MAC, BOS, MONITOR,
  MK, PHONE, PRINTER, TPHONE, JOB, OTHER, GOZAR
)
values (
  @ID, @NAME, @INNUM, @TNUM, @PHONENUM, @IP, @MAC, @BOS, @MONITOR,
  @MK, @PHONE, @PRINTER, @TPHONE, @JOB, @OTHER, @GOZAR
);
";
```

Comment: TNK FOR UR KINDNESS
NOW NEW ERROR 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'شسیشسی' to data type int.'

Comment: @Captain AR: Time to debug: put a breakpoint, inspect all the bind variables' values, find where `شسیشسی` has been assigned...